# DIY BNC to F-connector or RCA?

Tags: coax, rca, bnc

I've searched for this until I'm starting to get sick.  I decided to just ask for help.  My friend has a CCTV camera with the typical BNC/Power cable, but he doesn't have a DVR.  I have zero interest in buying any adapters or anything for that matter.

If possible, I would like to simply chop off the BNC end that goes to the DVR and splice either an F-connector or an RCA connector - allowing the camera to hook directly to a TV.  From my Google searches, nobody has appeared to have ever done this.

Is this possible without buying any extra junk and if so, how would one go about doing it? I have tons of coax/F-connector cables and RCA cables, but there's only the single BNC cable to work with.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Of course it's possible. What exactly is stopping you? Just do it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it's a normal composite video CCTV camera (most are). You should be able to splice on a RCA connector and plug it into the composite input of your TV.

Splicing on a F connector and plugging it into the antenna input is not going to work.

Comment: Are you saying to just splice an RCA connector onto the end of the BNC plug?  It seems like some of the commercial adapters looked sort of like that.

Answer (score 1):

As Peter has said if it is a standard definition analog camera then you can terminate to an RCA plug and connect to a composite input, typically yellow coloured.

Just be aware there are some HD over coax cameras that will not work this way.

Adaptors are a few dollars at most and this is actually fairly common. Some cheap CCTV test screens have RCA composite inputs, not BNC and I have seen some dome cameras with RCA test points. So not something hugely unusual.

Have used BNC to RCA adaptors many times.

Comment: Okay, I'm liking the sounds of this.  I'm fairly confident in my electronics skills in most areas, but I haven't messed with coax very much, and I've never fiddled with BNC (except to plug it into my own cameras and dvr). So this might be an elementary question, but while I've got some brains helping me out - can two lengths of coax be spliced together by soldering the shields of each end and the main center wires to one another?  Sorry for the poor nomenclature, but this is where I intend to add BNC and coax modification to my electronics knowledge portfolio...

Comment: I'm just searching how to splice two lengths of coax, and most of the information seems to indicate that I should use an F-connector on both ends and a barrel plug in-between... It just seems like for my purposes, I could just solder the wires together... I'm going to go ahead and assume that this causes some sort of interference?

Comment: @Shane - yes, you can splice 2 coax cables as you describe. But. The splice will be a region of the cable where the impedance of the cable has changed from specification, and will cause a (slight) distortion in the signal. And the higher the signal frequency, the greater the effect. If you're just using CCTV (a few MHz) and short cables you may get away with it. Also be very careful to insulate the center splice in a very robust manner - you'd be amazed how Murphy will bite you in the long run if you leave it exposed and vulnerable to shorting to the shield.

Comment: The join can also become a prime spot for corrosion if not adequately sealed. Had an annoying intermittent fault and finally found a badly done solder joint that had only been wrapped in electrical tape. It is less hassle to just get a BNC to RCA adaptor or an RCA compression fitting, although that will require some tools.

Comment: Well thanks for the help everyone.  I'm kind of *ashamed* to have to ask a question about electronics, as I'm supposed to be the electronics wizard in my area... Lol, I am known as "The Scientist" to some - but any time anyone says anything like that to me, I tell them that there are much smarter people in the world - such as you guys :D  Thanks for keeping me modest all you geniuses.  Now, to see if my friend will let me chop into his only BNC cable...lmao